# Google fake pages hack

Tags: google, hacking, hacked-site

Last week a hacker found a backdoor in a very old Joomla website I have and created thousands of fake pages using .htaccess rewriting and editing the index.php. He also deleted sitemap and robots txt files.

[image: Hundreds of Thousands of these entries created]

So I took action and reverted back and hopefully soon Google will fix the indexed pages by removing them as all are 404. In order to avoid any new incident I converted the website to a static HTML as it almost never changes.

Except taking action to avoid this happening again, what is the fastest possible fix for this situation? Is is enough all these pages to return 404 or I should take other action(s) as well.

Comment: "So I took action and reverted back" - this is NOT how to deal with a compromised server.

Comment: I see your point and second that, however it was not a compromised server just a compromised docker container. The hacker could not harm the host machine.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "harm" - and even with a compromised docker container they can harm you personally and other people.

Comment: As long as container recreated - and with a completely different image - and as long as the container did not have any special permissions to manipulate the host, I do not see any security issue on host side. Is there anything else I miss?

Comment: How do you ensure they don't exploit the same vulnerability to do the same thing (or worse) again?

Answer (score 1):

First, just replacing the files is not adequate to deal with a hacked server.  At the very least you need to wipe it clean and restart.  All sorts of things might have been done such as cron jobs, innocuous looking files etc.

Assuming that these are links to your site then you only need to ensure that a **404** is returned for every invalid page, or even **410**.

Comment: Here's Google Tool to remove content due to hacking: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?sjid=4083422649023604496-NA and here's some Google recommended advice on dealing with hacked sites: https://web.dev/articles/hacked